# install monterey stuck on pair keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard

i installed macos monterey as fresh way, before install format Mac and Mac-Data with disk util and install macos, after setup complete, showing a message : you format hard manually ... i just click go ro recovery, then in next reboot language chooser screen shows, first want mouse or magic track connection, i turned it off and on again, trackpad detected successfully, then want keyboard, i have magic keyboard2, i turned it off and on again, but unfortunatly my keyboard not paired and stucked in this screen

i tried to reboot my l mac mini with m1 chip to refovery, but holding power key not showing startup options

can any one help to me?

thanks

Comment: Bookmark this - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac Boot options are different on M1 Macs compared to Intel.

Comment: @tetsujin i know, if you read my question, i say : holding power button

Comment: I read your question. Did you read the page I sent you to? The two are not the same thing, boot & bluetooth connection. I made the effort to find the page for you, at least have the courtesy to read it.

Comment: @DJafari Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @AlexJohnson no, i just connect usb keyboard to solve this problem